# Tabulary on a rotated page does not use correct \textwidth

Tags: tables, rotating, landscape, tabulary

I'm trying to have a tabulary-table on a landscape page in a portrait document.

Because I want to have the table use the full width, I tried to set it width to `\textwidth`, but the width of the table is only as wide as the textwidth is on a portrait page.

How can I make the table using the correct width?

Since I am using XeLaTeX the MWE contains Unicode-Characters!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{lscape}
\title{MWE – tabulary rotate}
\subtitle{Textwidth is way to small}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{RJL}
\emph{Left} & \emph{Middle} & \emph{Right} \\
This is a text that shall be a litte bit longer, and longer!
& And even this text is meant to be not so short that it is just simple short…
& Also there is the last column, which shall not be just a handful of letters
but an full sentence instead, that doesn't not even to make sense!
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\linewidth` can be used instead:

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{RJL}
```

Package `lscape` does rotate `\textheight`, but does not change `\textwidth`.
Probably a bug.

**Update:** It is a design compromise, see David Carlisle's comment.

Comment: not a bug, just a design compromise. `lscape` doesn't rotate the page head/foot and if you change `\textwidth` many settings of the page head went wrong. `\linewidth` is normally used within the page so it was safer to set that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Oh +1 for giving the right answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Is there a method to avoid the resulting `overfull \hbox`es?

Comment: @kando there are no overfull hboxes that result from this answer. If you have overfull boxes perhaps some text doesn't fit something but you should open a new question, not in a comment on an old answer, and give an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Sounds good - I was worried of duplication : j

Comment: @kando whatever your problem is it's almost certainly a duplicate (there are only so many ways a box can be full) but it won't be a duplicate of _this question_.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : [Question asked here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264657/scrlayer-scrpage-package-landscape-environment-creates-overfull-hbox)