# pdflscape and tikzpagenodes problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, landscape

I am having problems getting the `tikzpagenodes` package to work with the `pdflscape` package. I want to access the nodes `(current page text area)` and `(current page marginpar area)` when rotating a page to landscape, but I am surprised by the results.

My problem is somewhat similar to the one in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91105/tikz-anchors-of-special-node-current-page-seem-to-be-incorrect-in-landscape), though for me the `(current page)` node works as expected.

Here is an MWE where I try to draw the outline of the node, both before and after starting the rotation. I am compiling this with `pdflatex` and also with lualatex in MiKTeX 2.9 (I actually probably need to use `lualatex` for memory reasons).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{sideways}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead{\tikz [remember picture,overlay] \draw [red] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{sideways}
\blindtext
\end{landscape}

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{sideways}
\begin{landscape}
\blindtext
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The output I am seeing is that the text is correctly placed, while the tikz node is much too small:

[image: Result]

The reason I am putting the `\tikz\draw` inside a fancyheading is that I want to use this for placing headers and footers on a landscape page (yes, I know I probably shouldn't...).

I have also observed the 'inverse' of this behaviour, where the `(current page text area)` is placed correctly, and the text is occupying the region now outlined by the `(current page text area)` node, but I was not able to reproduce this behaviour in a reasonably small MWE.

Answer (score 6):

I think I'm getting a handle on this now.

There is a quirk in the packages `lscape`/`pdflscape`: they change `\textheight` but not `\textwidth`. This is a [design choice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/tabulary-on-a-rotated-page-does-not-use-correct-textwidth), apparently. Nevertheless, it confuses `tikzpagenodes`, which uses both lengths to define its nodes.

I have a solution that solves my particular problem: redefining the `landscape` environment by resetting `\textheight` to its original, non-rotated, value. I cannot detect any side-effects, but I'm holding off on accepting the answer in case someone else does, or perhaps can offer a more satisfying solution. Not that this question has generated any interest so far..

Here is my (now, working) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{sideways}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \draw [red] (current page text area.south west) rectangle 
                (current page text area.north east);
            \draw [green] (current page header area.south west) rectangle 
                (current page header area.north east);
            \draw [blue] (current page footer area.south west) rectangle 
                (current page footer area.north east);
            \draw [black] (current page marginpar area.south west) rectangle 
                (current page marginpar area.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}           
    }
}

% This fixes the \textheight problem
\newlength{\oldtextheight}
\let\oldlandscape\landscape
\def\landscape{\setlength{\oldtextheight}{\textheight}\oldlandscape\setlength{\textheight}{\oldtextheight}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{sideways}
\blindtext

{\huge\bf Text height = \the\textheight}

{\huge\bf Text width = \the\textwidth}


\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{sideways}
\blindtext

{\huge\bf Text height = \the\textheight}

{\huge\bf Text width = \the\textwidth}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your new landscape definition will throw an error if you have `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{whatever.png}` within a landscape environment. Something like `! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.` While `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{whatever.png}` will continue to work. Perhaps there is a way to correct this. Note it seems parameter `height` is the culprit here-being disabled.