# Geometry: showframe + landscape

Tags: margins, geometry, landscape, pdflscape

I'm using `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` and I'm seeing that when I use a `landscape` environment (added by `pdflscape` package) the frame doesn't seem to be OK.

Is this an erratum?  Is there any way to correct this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[outer=25mm,inner=35mm,vmargin=20mm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=15pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
Hello.  First page.  Everything ok.

\begin{landscape}
Why is the frame off?
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: The problem is that landscape rotates only the textbody. The footer is now on the left and this means the meaning of values like "text width" and "text height" depends on if you are inside or outside the text body: Outside the text height is the length from header to footer and inside the height of the content? Imho would have to patch `landscape` (so that is adds a marker on landscape pages) and geometry to get a correct result.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was thinking the same... this smelled like a bug.  Do you have any idea if this has already come up before?

Comment: I would say the word "bug" is a big harsh. landscape is doing some complicated page manipulations things and a simple option like showframe don't have to pay attention to such manipulations. It only would be nice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't want to be ungrateful, I just don't know how else to call it :P

Comment: @MarioS.E. The word you are looking for is "feature".  "bugs" are what you find in other people's packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, that sounds way better!.  On other subjects, shouldn't `geometry` be "aware" of the `landscape` environment?

Comment: @MarioS.E. well in general two contributed packages written by different authors in different centuries typically don't combine that well automatically, but in this particular case I suspect not. landscape was designed _not_ to affect the page geometry, in particular the page head and foot stay in portrait orientation (which is why `\textwidth` doesn't change)) It basically just applies `\rotatebox{90}{}` to the content of each page _without_ changing the page geometry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why does `\textheight` change but not `\textwidth`? I would expect, based on your description that *neither* would change.

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure I understand your question, lscape makes \textheight the new page height (the old width) but leaves \textwidth as it was so the page head works. (Heiko's answer gives the detail if you ignore the scurrilous comments questioning this design decision:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So it *does* change the page geometry. Just it only changes *half* of it. If it didn't change it, `\textheight` would *also* remain unchanged.

Comment: @cfr well only if you choose to define geometry in that way. What I mean was that lscape is designed to rotate the page body while leaving the page head and foot the same size and position in portrait position. Practically that means changing \textheight (so the output routine splits the text flow for the new "short" length, but keeping \textwitdth the same (as popular packages like fancyhdr use that to set the page head) so that means textwidth and textheight end up being the same, but life's complicated:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sadly, yes, it is. Right now, the best work around I have assumes that `\textheight` and `\textwidth` are constant throughout the document so that I can save their values to macros at the beginning and count on the saved values for laying out every page, whether in portrait or landscape. If `\textheight` didn't change in landscape, I could use that value which would be sensitive to changes. Or if `\textheight` and `\textwidth` were switched, I could use them appropriately in landscape. The problem is that I can't access the `\textheight` at all in landscape as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cfg `\linewidth` and `\columnwidth` are both set to the old value of `\textheight`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a ["design comprimise"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/tabulary-on-a-rotated-page-does-not-use-correct-textwidth/110959#comment244075_110959) in package `lscape` (in other packages it would be called "design flaw" ;-), of course). Environment `landscape` only rotates `\textheight` and `\textwidth` remains unchanged. However package `geometry` expects unchanged values, thus it gets surprised with `\textheight` having the old value of `\textwidth`.

The following example fixes this in package `geometry`'s `\Gm@vrule` that draws the vertical lines. The fixed version uses `\gmshow@textheight` instead of `\textheight`. Outside environment `landscape` the macro `\gmshow@textheight` expands to `\textheight`. Inside it expands to `\gmshow@@textheight` that is initialized with the text height (available in `\hsize`) at the begin of environment `landscape`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  outer=25mm,
  inner=35mm,
  vmargin=20mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  headheight=15pt,
  showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\gmshow@textheight}{\textheight}
\newdimen\gmshow@@textheight
\g@addto@macro\landscape{%
  \gmshow@@textheight=\hsize
  \renewcommand*{\gmshow@textheight}{\gmshow@@textheight}%
}
\def\Gm@vrule{%
  \vrule width 0.2pt height\gmshow@textheight depth\z@
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Hello.  First page.  Everything ok.

\begin{landscape}
  \Huge
  \noindent
  top left\hfill top right\par
  \vfill
  \noindent
  bottom left\hfill bottom right
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Oi, I saw that:-)

Comment: Nice answer!  I'll keep the question open just so see if someone else comes with a different approach (I don't want to discourage other answers), but your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to give the `\textheight` for use as a length directly? That is, I found this question trying to solve a problem and the `showframe` issue is a symptom but the main problem is that I get background text in the wrong place. Essentially, I'm trying to answer my own question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172225/39222. I can work around it by saving `\textheight` and `\textwidth` but then the values are insensitive to any changes in these values in the document. Plus my solution there feels very kludgey and I am sure it will break in the first whisper of a breeze.

Comment: Excellent code and solution (I had exactly the same probl...doubt one year later). Plus, this answer and comments in this page explain very well the whole context about landscapes and geometries.