# Scrlayer-scrpage package + landscape environment creates overfull \hbox

Tags: pdflscape, scrlayer-scrpage

Using the `scrlayer-scrpage` package with a `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package creates a pair of `overfull \hbox` badboxes.

Some users have commented that they do not receive the badbox.

### Version Information:

I'm using Tex Live 2014 (TeXworks, pdfLaTex).

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
scrlayer-scrpage.sty    14/12/2013 v0.9.1548 package (end user interface for scrlayer)
scrlayer.sty    31/10/2013 v0.9.1480 package (defining layers and page styles)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
pdflscape.sty    2008/08/11 v0.10 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % improved header commands. [supercedes `fancyhdr' package].
\usepackage{pdflscape}                  % landscape page layout.

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
a
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

### Pic

[image: Pic of MWE errors]

Comment: Why `\usepackage{mwe}` and `lipsum`? They seem entirely superfluous. And you don't need `graphicx` or `float` for the MWE, either, although presumably those are not superfluous in your document itself.

Comment: I get no complaints about bad boxes when I compile your code. Please ensure that your MWE can be used to reproduce the problem you are asking about before posting it as it is difficult to help otherwise!

Comment: @cfr : mwe was used at first because I thought that figures caused the bad box. lipsum was used to demonstrate that text did not cause the bad box. I proved myself wrong, however, as I still got a bad box with just the `a`.  I reduced the code in the question, as prescribed.

Comment: But loading `mwe` and `lipsum` does nothing. Loading the first is unnecessary anyway and loading the second is pointless if you don't use it. To demonstrate what you said, you'd need to include a figure and/or text in the document. As I say, I get no bad boxes with just `a`.

Comment: @cfr : Yep. There were originally mwe figures and lipsum text in the code, prior to posting the code. I removed the figures and lipsum text later in the debugging process.  I forgot to remove the packages before posting the code.  I later removed the packages from the posted code, since you mentioned this.

Comment: @cfr : Are you using Tex Live 2015?  Perhaps an update fixed this?

Comment: @kando maybe: With the code given and an up to date TL 2015 I get no overfull box. (I also have a bleeding edge KOMA-Script version `2015/08/11 v3.18.2175`…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled your code without errors and warnings with the following package versions:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
scrlayer-scrpage.sty    2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (end user interface for scrlayer)
scrlayer.sty    2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (defining layers and page styles)
scrkbase.sty    2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
pdflscape.sty    2008/08/11 v0.10 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

I hope you can see that you should update your tex distribution. Your used versions are a little bit outdated!  See for example `article.cls` and `scrlayer-scrpage.sty`.

BTW: `\listfiles` should be better the first line, so first `\listfiles`, in the second line follows `\documentclass ...`.

Comment: This is all useful info.  I requested a distribution update.  (It can take between 3-6 months for them to get it to us, so: not particularly the answer I wanted, but the answer I needed.) Thanks!

Comment: Defense contractor - everything goes through IT security purgatory before coming to us : j  We like to think begging helps